# Can't put a basemap in its Precise location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, georeferencing, basemap

I am a total beginner with ArcGIS.

( My software info: ArcGIS Desktop Version 10.1 ) (Windows 8.1 Pro).

I want to use a raster as a Basemap for my city, I know the coordinates of my city. my question is how can I Set this raster in its Precise location? I tried to set up the exact coordinates of my city but when I try to project a point shapefile to it, the points shows up somewhere ELSE and not on the raster.(even though they have the same coordinates of the raster which is my city's coordinate).